# Taking a value from the Gen monad to the IO monad

Tags: haskell, monads, quickcheck

I'm generating a minesweeper board and want to generate the board based on where the first click (actually not a click, just a string written in the cmd representing a click) was done. This is a problem though, as I have to mix the Gen and IO monad. Is there a way to convert Gen a to IO a?

I found [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:generate) function. Which would do exactly what i want. But it isn't available for import.

Comment: I realised that I can use sample' :: Gen a -> IO [a] and take the first result. But that is a bit of an ugly hack.

Comment: @Sibi It is a monad from the QuickCheck module, source here: [link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/src/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#Gen)

Comment: It is available for import. Just `import Test.QuickCheck.Gen`.

Comment: @András Kovács It's not, I have tried. You can't even find it in Hoogle. But I've found out a answer now, coming up soon.

Comment: It is a function from the public interface of that package. The package in fact exports everything it defines. If you are not able to import it, there's a bug somewhere. Perhaps you are using a wrong version. Show your error messages.

Comment: @SiXoS I just imported it in my ghci from my QuickCheck 2.7.6.

Comment: @SiXoS: It's on the first page of FP Complete Hoogle! https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=generate

Comment: @AndrásKovács @n.m. @Tom Ellis How do i check the QuickCheck version? When I import Test.QuickCheck.Gen(generate): Module `Test.QuickCheck.Gen' does not export `generate'

Comment: @SiXoS `ghc-pkg list` on the terminal is one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I realised that using Gen was a bad idea and are now using StdGen instead

This is not only more practical in my case but also generates a better randomness